# Firefox - what are all the possible CSS classes/elements I can use in userChrome.css?

Tags: firefox, css

It's great that we can customize the look and feel of the browser itself by changing styles in `userChrome.css`, but I have no idea what I can change, save for a few example files I found floating around the internet. Is there any documentation or file that has all the CSS definitions usable in `userChrome.css`?